# How to add an vector color icon in ExtendedFloatingActionButton

Tags: android, floating-action-button, materialbutton

I'm trying to add a **color vector** icon in an **ExtendedFloatingActionButton** from **google material** 
but it is showing a black background in the icon.

On Preview of layout, it looks alright but when run on mobile it shows black background near the icon.

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
     android:id="@+id/floating_btn_take_test"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
     android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
     android:text="@string/txt_take_test"
     android:textColor="@color/primaryColor"
     app:backgroundTint="@color/color_white"
     app:elevation="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
     app:icon="@drawable/ic_color_icon"
     app:iconTintMode="add"
     app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
     app:rippleColor="@color/secondaryColor"
     app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearance_Button" />

<style name="ShapeAppearance_Button" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.SmallComponent">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">@dimen/dimen_10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/dimen_30dp</item>
</style>
```

How to remove the black background around the icon?

Comment: are you using AndroidX one?

Comment: yes, I am using androidx @ShaluTD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are trying to add a icon that has different colours to a FAB?

When doing that, make sure you add `app:tint="@null"`.
In your case the xml should look like this.

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floating_btn_take_test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
    android:text="@string/txt_take_test"
    android:textColor="@color/primaryColor"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/color_white"
    app:elevation="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_color_icon"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
    app:rippleColor="@color/secondaryColor"
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearance_Button"
    app:tint="@null" />

<style name="ShapeAppearance_Button" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.SmallComponent">
   <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
   <item name="cornerSize">@dimen/dimen_10dp</item>
   <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/dimen_30dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try to use `app:tint` as below:-

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/color_white"
    app:tint="@null"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_color_icon"
/>
```

OR

Change `app:backgroundTint="@null"`

Comment: Solved by changing the `app:tint` or `app:backgroundTint="@null"` ?

Comment: Solved by app:tint="@null"